# Firebase Email Verification Android

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying having a little bit of a problem in my application which uses firebase to store usernames and send verification emails. I have gotten to the point where you can create an account and it will send a verification link. So, I was wondering since if someone registers with an email firebase automatically registers it, so can't a person that just type a random email, say for example test@test.com and then the real owner of test@test.com tries registering but can't because the email is already taken even though the imposter didn't/can't verify it the verification link. Is there any way to make it so that the email is only registered in the firebase auth once the verification link has successfully been clicked by the person that really owns that email?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Also I am very new to firebase)

Here is my Java class code:

https://pastebin.com/HP7Q15Gh

Answer (score 0):

When you send the email verification, it won't be verified until the link is clicked, so even if `User A` tries to verify `UserB@example.com`, it will send the link, but won't create the account until the email is verified. If `User B` tries to create an account, another email would be sent to `UserB@example.com`, which they could verify. The template very clearly says:

> If you didn’t ask to verify this address, you can ignore this email.

This would allow the "real" user to create an account with their own address if the wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to end-to-end test email verification try [EmailE2E.com](https://www.emaile2e.com?utm=43161997) — it's free.

You can send and receive emails from randomly generated inboxes via an API.

It's perfect for testing Firebase, Amazon Cognito, or other OAuth providers that use email verification codes during sign up. Plus it has clients in Java and JS.